# How to build stand alone Python program that has module dependencies? (Tweet2Vec)

Tags: python, dependency-management, word2vec, python-module

I am building a program that uses the Tweet2Vec python module. How would I package the Tweet2Vec module and its dependencies so that the end-user does not have to worry about module dependencies?

I've downloaded all dependencies onto my computer.

Prerequisites

- Python 2.7
- Theano and all dependencies (latest)
- Lasagne (latest)
- Numpy

**End goal is the user is able runs Python code without worrying about installing dependencies.**

Comment: Have you tried pyinstaller?

Comment: No I havent, but this looks like the solution I was looking for. Thank you.